# sqlite select records that didn't exist the previous day

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

given the following table 'files' with columns

```
repo_name, file_name, size, downloads, date_stamp 
and values:
('repo1', 'file1', 100, 7, '2019-08-15')
('repo1', 'file1', 100, 5, '2019-08-08')
('repo1', 'file2', 100, 10, '2019-08-15')
('repo1', 'file3', 100, 10, '2019-08-08')
('repo2', 'file1', 100, 10, '2019-08-15')
('repo2', 'file2', 100, 10, '2019-08-15')
```

I want to select all combinations of repo_name/file_name that:
1) are new for 08-15, in other words did not exist on 08-08 and sum the downloads values.
2) do not exist for 08-15 but were there on 08-08
3) exist on both 08-08 and 08-15 and sum the difference in downloads for those dates

for 3), this seems to work:

```
for row in cur.execute('select a.repo_name, a.file_name, a.downloads - b.downloads from files a inner join files b on a.repo_name = b.repo_name and a.file_name = b.file_name where a.date_stamp = ? and b.date_stamp = ? ', (today, daysback_7):
    print(row)
```

This does not sum the values but returns:
('repo1', 'file1', 2) the only repo_name/file_name combination that exists on both dates and the difference between the downloads values. I need to see if I can sum the difference values in one query because I only want the total. Worst case, I can iterate through the rows and sum the values.

for 2) I just want to know the number of repo_name/file_name combinations that were there 08-08 but not 08-15, in other words the files were deleted:

```
for row in cur.execute('select repo_name, file_name from files where date_stamp = ? except select repo_name, file_name from files where date_stamp = ?', (daysback_7, today)):
    print(row)
```

for 1) I can get the repo_name/file_name combinations but I'd like to get the downloads values too. This is what I have:

```
for row in cur.execute('select repo_name, file_name from files where date_stamp = ? except select repo_name, file_name from files where date_stamp = ? ', (today, daysback_7)):
    print(row)
```

It returns:

```
('repo1', 'file2')
('repo2', 'file1')
('repo2', 'file2')
```

But I cannot include the column downloads otherwise it includes the row for repo1/file1 which is not new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Some of these require a modern version of sqlite (3.25 or newer) due to use of window functions:

```
-- 1 - Sum of downloads of files that only exist on 2019-08-15
SELECT sum(downloads)
FROM (SELECT downloads
           , first_value(date_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY repo_name, file_name
                                               ORDER BY date_stamp) AS first_date
      FROM files)
WHERE first_date = '2019-08-15';
sum(downloads)
--------------
30

-- 2 - Files that exist on 2019-08-08 but not 2019-08-15
SELECT repo_name, file_name FROM files WHERE date_stamp = '2019-08-08'
EXCEPT
SELECT repo_name, file_name FROM files WHERE date_stamp = '2019-08-15';
repo_name   file_name
----------  ----------
repo1       file3

- 3 - Sum of difference in downloads for files present on both dates
SELECT sum(diff)
FROM (SELECT downloads - lag(downloads, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY repo_name, file_name
                                                     ORDER BY date_stamp) AS diff
      FROM files
      WHERE date_stamp IN ('2019-08-08', '2019-08-15'));
sum(diff)
----------
2
```

All three benefit from an index on `files(repo_name, file_name, date_stamp)`.

Comment: Perfect! As a follow-up, how would you get a count of the files that no longer exist on 2019-08-15, case -- 2 --?